# Is it fair to use the PNT to prove a big conjecture?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Say that you were on the brink of proving the Twin Prime conjecture or the Goldbach conjecture, and your final chapter in the proof, where everything fit together, needed to show that a certain function increased at a slower rate than some other function. If you used this approximation for the amount of primes between $x$ and $2x$, $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ as one of your functions, would your proof still be valid? And if not, is there a similar function you could use that might achieve the same effect without assuming that the Riemann Hypothesis is true? By "same effect" I mean, a more correct function.

Comment: The PNT is more than just $\pi(x)\approx \frac{x}{\ln x}$; it provides specific error bounds. RH just makes those bounds better.  Any proof would have to take bounds on the error term into account, regardless of whether you need RH for them or not.  You'll have to be a lot more specific to get more specific advice, I'm afraid.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki Could you point me to those bounds?

Comment: The answers to my question about $\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149315/whats-known-about-the-number-of-primes-in-the-range-n-2n , should give a good starting point.

Comment: (It's also worth noting that while the same tools that were necessary to prove the PNT will be necessary to prove these conjectures, it's _highly_ unlikely that they'll be even remotely sufficient given how well-developed those tools are, so there's a lot of reason to have some innate skepticism about such a proof - but that's a different matter entirely.)

Comment: @StevenStadnicki I understand your skepticism and welcome it! I was just wondering how effective/useful the PNT really was and what you could use the bounds for. Thanks for your link, it's a great starting point.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime-counting_function_in_terms_of_the_logarithmic_integral is quite clear about  some effective bounds

Comment: You can use whatever prior results you want as long as you properly cite them, or at least acknowledge the original author. As to whether you've picked the right prior result, that's another question.

Comment: @Steven I get the sense that Linus is concerned about plagiarism, which, of course, does happen in mathematics, though perhaps not as much as in, say, poetry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're trying to do original research in mathematics, no tools are off the table. You can assume the prime number theorem, Fermat's last theorem, and all kinds of other major results which have been proved. In fact, you can even assume results which have not been proved, provided that you make this clear in the statement of your theorem. For example, a conditional proof of the twin prime conjecture on the Riemann hypothesis would certainly be publishable, even though it wouldn't resolve the conjecture (until RH is eventually proved).

But as has been pointed out in the comments, it's unlikely that this sort of black box approach will be sufficient to solve major existing problems. It seems far more likely that you'd need to bring in elements from the proof of the prime number theorem (suitably modified).