# The Growth of Primes

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I've been experimenting with the function $π(x)$ such that $π(x)$ counts the number of primes from $1$ to $x$.

I found that after $10$, $π(x^2) - π(\lfloor \frac{x^2}{2} \rfloor)$ is always larger than $x$.

However, after doing some research (see Prime Number Theorem), I'm a bit confused because the number of primes grows more and more slowly.

Wouldn't this mean, at some point, $x$ will be greater than $π(x^2) - π(\lfloor \frac{x^2}{2} \rfloor)$ again or am I just being stupid?

Comment: Also, I'm trying to use MathJax with the guide but it's not working?

Comment: Hi, welcome to MSE! You can typeset $f(x^2) - f(\lfloor \frac{x^2}{2} \rfloor)$ most simply (in my opinion) with the source code `$f(x^2) - f(\lfloor \frac{x^2}{2} \rfloor)$` :)

Comment: So, if you take $g(x) = \frac{x}{\log x}$, and compute $g(x^2) - g(x^2 / 2)$, what do you get?

Comment: That would mean $f(x^2)−f(x^2/2)$ is increasing since the growth of logs is very slow, right? But why did you choose that function in particular? I don't think it represents the number of prime numbers

Comment: The [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) is usually denoted $\pi(x)$

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just chose f(x) because I don't like copy and pasting symbols

Comment: One of the nice things about MathJax is that you don't have to copy-paste anything! To get $\pi$, you can just type `$\pi$`. Dmitry's comment is exactly right - he chose that function in particular because of the Prime Number Theorem. Since you mentioned it in your post, I think he assumed you're familiar with its content. What PNT says is basically exactly that $f(x)$ is approximately $\frac x{\log x}$!

Comment: By the Prime Number Theorem, $\pi (x^2 ) - \pi \left( {\left\lfloor {\frac{{x^2 }}{2}} \right\rfloor } \right) \sim \frac{{x^2 }}{{4\log x}}$ for large $x$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149315/whats-known-about-the-number-of-primes-in-the-range-n-2n for useful bounds on $\pi(2n)-\pi(n)$ (which you can apply to your question by taking $n=(1/2)x^2$).